# Azure traffic manager returns 400 with Cdn enpoints

Tags: azure-cdn, azure-traffic-manager

I have problem with Azure traffic manager.

I have traffic manager with Priority configuration. And two external endpoints that linked to CDN endpoints urls.

---

url.trafficmanager.net - traffic manager

cdn1.azureedge.net - the first endpoint with priority 1 - live and returns the web-site with Status 200 OK

cdn2.azureedge.net - the second endpoint with priority 2 - live and returns the web-site with Status 200 OK

But when I try to open  url.trafficmanager.net then it returns 400 error.

---

I saw this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-traffic-manager but I can't set up the custom domain for the second cdn endpoint, because Azure says that the other cdn endpoint has the same custom domain. Also, our domain registrator can't create two CNAME records with same hosts

Answer (score 0):

As the providing [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-traffic-manager#set-up-custom-domain-on-azure-cdn-and-azure-traffic-manager), you don't need to create two CNAME records with the same hosts, you just need to update the value of the existing CNAME record `cdnverify` subdomain for the second endpoint when you set up the custom domain as Azure CDN uses the `cdnverify` subdomain to validate the DNS mapping to complete this registration process.

For example, you might have added these two CNAME records for the first CDN endpoint.

```
cdnverify.cdndemo.custom.com CNAME cdnverify.cdndemoakamai.azureedge.net
cdndemo.custom.com CNAME cdndemo.trafficmanager.net
```

Once you have added the custom domain `cdndemo.custom.com` to the first endpoint, **update** the first DNS mapping you created so that the custom domain is mapped to your second CDN endpoint.

```
cdnverify.cdndemo.custom.com CNAME cdnverify.cdndemoverizon.azureedge.net
```

After the above steps, you could test the URL from the custom domain `cdndemo.custom.com`. Please let me know if this works or you need further help.